# Nightmares - Personagem não se movimenta, parado na animação Idle

Tags: unity3d

Estou seguindo o passo a passo do Nightmares no Unity3D, porem seguindo os tutoriais do Nils me deparei com um problema, depois de terminar o script o personagem não se movimenta na tela de teste, ele fica parado na animação Idle, e ela não continua, carrega apenas 1 vez. Obrigado pela ajuda, grande abraço!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;                //Velocidade do jogador

    Vector3 movement;                       //Vetor responsavel pelo movimento
    Animator anim;                          //Responsavel pela transiçao da animaçao 
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;              //Responsavel pela fisica do objeto
    int floorMask;                              //Mascara de chao
    float camRayLenght = 100f;              //Informaçoes para o raycast

    void Awake ()
    {
        //Atribuir a mascara da camada. 
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");

        //Atribuir as referencias.
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();

    }

    void FixedUpadate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");
        Move(h,v);
        turning();
        Animating(h,v); 

    }

    //Movimenta o jogador
    void Move (float h, float v)
    {
        // Determina o movimento
        movement.Set(h,0f,v);

        //Normaliza o movimento 
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        //Efetua o movimento no personagem
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
    }

    //Gira o jogador
    void turning()
    {
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit floorHit;

        if (Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLenght, floorMask)) 
        {
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);


        }

    }
    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = (h!= 0f || v!= 0f);
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);

    }


}
```

Comment: Oi estou com o mesmo problema.. Kk' Esperando por uma resposta tbm haha. Mas aki.. Pelo jeito vc tbm ta tentando aprender e tals.. Vc tem quantos anos? xD

Comment: Fala amigo, eu tenho 24 anos. Pois é, acredito que várias pessoas tiveram o mesmo problema, Refiz o tutorial do zero duas vezes para tirar a dúvida na questão de variáveis e das funções, essa parte de programação é bem complicado pois a interpretação é Case Sensitive, porem não funcionou de forma alguma. Não quero esperar até iniciar o módulo de C++ no curso para começar a programar então estou já colocando algumas coisas em prática. Só espero que não demore para resolver essa questão, estou com esse problema dês das 10h e até agora não achei solução!

Comment: Me add na Steam ai: Sardovick

Comment: Adicionado Lucas. Velho eu estava indignado com o problema e buscando uma solução acabei entrando no Answers.Unity, percebi que várias pessoas tiveram o mesmo problema depois de atualizar para a versão 5. Não sei em que versão você está desenvolvendo, mas todos os tutoriais que eu achei desse game não havia essas duas caixas nos nodes, o Entry e nem o Exit, tenho minhas suspeitas de que falta alguma configuração nesses nodes ai. Vou ver se o Nils me responde no Youtube.

Comment: Cuidado galera, Entry e Exit não tem nada a ver com o problema, ele são soluções para facilitar a vida quando forem fazer outras coisas. Por causa de uma linha no código vocês estão espalhando desinformação que pode atrapalhar os outros que estão aprendendo.

Comment: @Lucas qual foi o teu problema?

Comment: Por causa de uma pergunta similar, esta pergunta [está *também* sendo discutida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4186/pergunta-erroneamente-marcada-como-duplicada). Eu também votei para fechá-la porque essencialmente trata-se de um erro de digitação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no código, veja:

```
void FixedUpadate()
```

É uma função interna do Unity, e deve ser escrita corretamente.

```
void FixedUpdate()
```

Veja como usar ela:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rD4OuPxsuk&list=PLa2bQ5uCFWA1RwL5QDkPHiOBrFska2Tj0

Comment: Valeu Nils deu certinho aqui tá rodando maroto já. Forte abraço!